# Witcher gear set bonus

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm playing the Witcher 3 and i just retrieved all "Griphon Witcher" schematics. I crafted the 2 swords and 2 pieces of armor. I was expecting to receive a set bonus.

Is there a set bonus? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no bonus set, but green items can be upgraded to better versions of themselves latter. Don't destroy them when you find a shiny brown sword !

Comment: Sage advice indeed, as many of the 'Enhanced' and 'Superior' diagrams require the previous tier item in order to craft them. So keep all your greens!

Comment: There are abilities (in the yellow tree) that give a bonus for wearing certain class of items, and they are named after those sets - however I'm not sure whether they work just on those sets or any armor of same class. Also, there is an achievement for wearing a full set (complete with crossbow that belongs to Superior class or higher I think)

Comment: @Deltharis those bonuses are for any armour in that class, not just (for example) Feline armour.

Comment: I just wanted to comment so that we can keep this answer up-to-date.  The new add-on "Blood and Wine" introduces set bonuses if you create the Grandmaster-crafted level 40 Witcher gear sets.  There is a bonus for wearing three of the pieces and an additional bonus for all six pieces.

Comment: This is not accurate. Witcher Grand Master level set *do* provide bonuses. [See this walkthough](http://guides.gamepressure.com/thewitcher3bloodandwine/guide.asp?ID=35457) to get started.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are set bonuses as you can CLEARLY read them when you look at the set pieces in the crafting page. ALTHOUGH, activating those set bonuses requires you to upgrade your set pieces to the grandmaster level.

Comment: Only a few sets have bonuses though. Griffin, ursine and feline have bonuses. Might be more, I'm not sure.

Comment: This is a new feature of the Blood & Wine expansion. As all of the other answers here are a year old, they were correct at the time. 5 of the 6 Witcher sets (griffin, feline, ursine, wolven and manticore) now have set bonuses once the grandmaster version is built. The viper set from Hearts of stone does not get bonuses.

Answer (score 1):

There is no bonus for wearing a full set of armor.

But you can get a skill in your character Menu, which will add you a bonus depending if you're wearing light, medium or heavy armor.

So in a way a full set (since it is of the same armor class) will still give you some benefit.

Comment: This is not accurate. Witcher Grand Master level set *do* provide bonuses. [See this walkthough](http://guides.gamepressure.com/thewitcher3bloodandwine/guide.asp?ID=35457) to get started.